# Bedürfen - Jemand bedarf der Schonung

Tags: verb, sentence-structure

Sagt man

```
jmd bedarf der Schonung
```

oder

```
jmd bedarf Schonung
```

? Ich würde aprioristisch die erste Option wählen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*bedürfen* bedarf normalerweise des Genitivs ;)

Da der Genitiv bei Feminina normalerweise gleich ist wie der Nominativ, wird er mit einem Artikel markiert, damit er erkennbar bleibt.

Das Verb kann allerdings auch (selten) mit dem Akkusativ verwendet werden und hört sich deswegen ungewohnt an. Richtig ist dein zweites Beispiel aber trotzdem (wenn man annimt, dass *Schonung* da ein Akkusativ ist). Dein erstes Beispiel ist aber mit Abstand gebräuchlicher.

Comment: Ich würde sagen: Jemand braucht Schonung, oder jemand benötigt Schonung, nicht jemand bedarf Schonung.

Comment: @gnasher729 Das war aber nicht die Frage.